# On the number of midpoint free subsets

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

A set $X$ of real numbers is called midpoint free if whenever $x,y$ are distinct elements of $X$ then $\frac{x+y}2 \not \in X$. What is number of midpoint free subsets of $\{1,2,...,n\}$?

Comment: Maybe I am counting wrong, but I don't find it is OEIS.  I get $2,4,7,13,22$.  It is close to http://oeis.org/A143823, but that one would not allow (for example) $\{1,2,8,9\}$ and your question does.

Answer (score 0):

The result is described by [OEIS sequence A051013](http://oeis.org/A051013), but no explicit (or even recursive) formula is given there, which indicates that none is known.